# build.phonegap.com not reading config.xml file

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using **online build service of phonegap** to build my app.

From few days it **is not workin**g. (error is not **reading config.xml** file for configuration).

My www.zip file contains *CSS,JS,Config.xml and index.html* files and folders

Please help me to solve this issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config.xml and Index.html must be at root directory of zip package, means you have to compress only **CONTENT** of www folder, not WWW folder itself.

For details click here http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/is-build-phonegap-com-working?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_comment&utm_content=reply_button&reply[id]=15076297#reply_15076297